# Switch between english and chinese characters on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: keyboard-layout, chinese

How to switch to Chinese characters? I set the hotkey to super+space but nothing happened. BTW, I am using i3 as my window manager and not using a desktop manager like gnome/kde. This is a regular ubuntu so ubuntu-desktop is installed and I am using it whenever I want to modify some settings that are not easy to do via a command line.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install a Chinese input method. The "Chinese" keyboard layout you have in your list of input sources is just an alias to *English (US)*.

So:

- Install a package with a Chinese input method. `ibus-pinyin` and `ibus-sunpinyin` are examples of such packages.
- Log out and log in again.
- Add the input method to your list of input sources.

Comment: 谢谢你！ I added Chinese - SunPinyin to the IBus Preferences and I can now type in 中文！